# How to make Karaf server run code before bundles

Tags: java, apache-karaf, karaf-maven-plugin, apache-karaf-feature

I have file in Karaf server which is deleted after some time I don't know why.
So I decide to run code to create the file before running the bundles that depends on it.

is that possible?

> > I have the code but I don't know where I can put it to run before bundle.

Some code to help saving my data source file before any bundles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people who are struggling here is my founding solution
implements ***BundleActivator***
and refrence it in pom as

```
<Bundle-Activator>org.ogra.bundle1.Activator</Bundle-Activator>
```

Refrence:
https://medium.com/@udayogra/write-simple-karaf-osgi-bundles-which-interact-with-each-other-in-eclipse-in-10-minutes-46c1bed0b460